# Navigate to same screen with different parameters using - ReactNavigation : React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have been trying to navigate to the same screen with different parameters on react-native application. It is a category screen, where I don't want the user to go back and select different categories to view products. I have made a screen where products from categories are displayed.

Below is my code:

```
  <View style={styles.horizontalSlider}>
         <FlatList
               horizontal
               showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
               data={this.state.DataSource}
               keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
               extraData={this.state.selectedItem}
               renderItem= { ({item}) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={(category) => navigate.push('CategoryScreen', {item})}>
                <ImageBackground style={styles.profileImgContainer} >
                <Image source={{ uri: item.images }} style={[styles.profileImg, , { borderColor: 'green', borderWidth:2 }]} />  
                </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
               )}
               />
            </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running into a specific problem or can you be more specific about what params you want to pass with navigate? Because it looks like you are already passing some parameters.

Comment: what different params you want to pass?

Comment: I have just added an image, so the round images in a slider are categories. I want to re-render the page on the basis of selection. Currently, it is showing products from Phone Category.  @wbd

Comment: @GauravRoy just added an image, please check. I am trying to open category data on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to navigate to the same screen with different parameters and be unable to go back, use `this.props.navigation.replace('CategoryScreen', { ...new params here... })`

If you want to change current navigation params without navigating, use `this.props.navigation.setParams()`

([navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html))

But your problem is not a navigation problem. You don't need multiple screens for that. Solve it with react. All you need to do is to render your list conditionally depending on what category (or circle item?) is currently selected. Store this information in state and use it in render

Comment: Exactly I am not looking for multiple screens. And thank you so much for your time and for sharing knowledge. I will try and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add unique key:

`this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: route, params: params, key: route + params.id })`

Comment: This mimics `navigation.push()` I guess